# how to send textbox value to json array

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

This may be very simple but i haven't found any correct approach for this yet.

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Destination)
```

Now, i want to know how to select value from these strongly typed html helper through jquery.
I want to post those selected input values to json array. Something like this:

{
    Name : "selected values from textbox",
    Destination : "selected value from dropdown" 
   }

I know how to do it with simple textbox:

```
@Html.TextBox("myname")
```

to get value from this textbox, simply use

```
$("myname").val();
```

Prevoiusly, i was able to send static data through json array to controller like this:

```
 <script> 
  var auth = {
        ClientId : "ApiIntegration",
        Origin : "Delhi",
    }

  $("#btnPost").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/api/Flight/About",
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(auth),
                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
        });
  });
```

But now, i want to populate value in Origin object of json from Textbox not static one this time.
My editor for is like this:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Origin)
```

please help me out.

Comment: What is the type/value of `Origin` and what is the signature of the method your posting to

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from input name like this:

```
$("input[name=myname]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jList=[];
var jOobj={Name:""};

jObj.Name=$("#myname").val();
jList.push(jObj);
```

Comment: comment ur sample code..so i can able to alter..tell me what error u got

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to always use promise when using AJAX. In your own case add datatype like so:

```
function SaveRecord(data) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: "/api/Flight/About",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data
            });
        }
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
 var data = {
      ClientId : $("#Name").val(),
      Origin : $(#Destination").val()
};

$.when(SaveRecord(data )).then(function (res) {
  ///handle success calback here
 }).fail(function(err){});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> About([FromBody]Authenticate auth)

Comment: here auth is posted as empty

Comment: Remember it is case sensitive so your Authenticate class should look like so: Public class Authenticate{ public string ClientId {get;set;} public string Origin {get;set;}}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id="Name" } })
@Html.DropDownList(model => model.Destination, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Destination" } })
<script type="text/javascript">


    var auth = {ClientId: "",Origin: ""}

    auth.ClientId = $("#Name").val();
    auth.Origin= $("#Destination option:selected").text();

    $("#btnPost").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/api/Flight/About",
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(auth),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var originvalue = $('#Origin').val();    

    $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/api/Flight/About",
                    type: "Post",
                    data: '{"ClientId":"ApiIntegration"' + ',"Origin":"' + originvalue + '"}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        alert(result);
                    }
            });
      });
```

Comment: it will print +Originalvalue+ in Username

Comment: Sorry i am not getting what you are trying to say. Originvalue is a variable which takes the value from your input using id as describe in first line.